# How to use material design components in androidx? Getting Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, material-design, androidx

I tried previous solutions provided on old same question [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012120/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-bottomnavigation-bottomnavigat).

I am using androix and want to add BottomNavigationView, I added `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.+'` in my app.gradle file, Here is my full gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.introtuce.business"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.+'
}
```

Here is my activity xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".home.Home">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@color/Black"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnavigationview"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am getting run-time error saying that

> Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

What could be the issue is it some version issue or I need to do something else to BottomNavigationView or (material designe) in android?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the version of com.google.android.material:material. If your connection with repository is not true use vpn and check the version. In almost cases,the reason is related to version(update to the last version) . And also do not use + sign .