# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line

Tags: android, kotlin

So i,ve search for many source to solve this problem. but i cant find how to solve this.

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
```

and this for my code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/container"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        />
```

Help me for solve this. thanks in advance

Comment: For test case remove this line `android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"`

Comment: which line is 29?

Answer (score 0):

There are constraints in com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView, however this should be in constraintLayout. Can this be the problem ? Also you have to check your drawables. [Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012120/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-bottomnavigation-bottomnavigat/53012285)

If these suggestions not solve your problem, could you put your complete layout here.

Comment: okay thank for your response, but there is one problem that make this problem come out. the problem is if your api level is higher than your handphone or your android simulator, so it will happened